# iptables doesn't redirect 443 to 8443 on local machine

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, redirect, port-forwarding

I want to redirect all the traffic from my computer from port 443 to port 8443. All the traffic is on the same machine. A proxy server is listening to port 8443 and i tried to add the following Rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlp3s0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

But my proxy didn't get any package.
wlp3s0 is my wifi adapter according to ifconfig.
What did i wrong?

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/1065983/iptables-prerouting-not-in-effect .

Answer (score 0):

If all your traffic is local traffic, so traffic originating from your computer, probably `-i wlp3s0` is the culpit here.

Your traffic most likely does not get routed via the `wlp3s0` interface, but rather via the `lo` ("loopback") interface.